# What is the difference between 落とす and なくす?

Tags: grammar

Consider the following two sentences:

> A:  かぎをなくしてしまいました。
>
> B:  かぎを落としてしまいました。

I have looked up in dictionaries and I found

- 落とす　：drop, lose, etc
- なくす　：lose
- 落ちる　：drop, fall, etc

I think the meaning of 落とす for lose is the same as 落ちてなくす which is drop followed by lose.

Is there any difference?

Comment: I think what you typed in your "answer" would be much better placed in your _question_ as "background research" (which is expected of any question). As it stands your question isn't a great question, because you don't tell us what you know and what you did to find an answer; and your "answer" isn't really a great answer either, because it doesn't really answer the question in any satisfactory way.

Comment: I think the nuance is same as in English, you can lose something without dropping it (for instance abstract stuff).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A: かぎを**なくして**しまいました。

In this sentence, you **lost** your keys.

> B: かぎを**落として**しまいました。

In this sentence, you **dropped** your keys.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Getting dropped is not necessarily getting lost and getting lost is not necessarily getting dropped. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, correct. There may be cases that you dropped your keys but you found it on the floor right away.

Comment: OK. It is important to note that I did not down vote your answer. I will neutralize it.

Comment: Hi downvoters, please consider it: Downvoting without any comments is really bad as it does not provide me as well as others about what is wrong and what it should be. Please kindly insist on confusing me. :-(

Comment: Also note that "鍵を落とした" implies that you lost the key, which makes (in this context) 落とす somewhat interchangeable with なくす. If you lost your key while riding a bicycle, you'd probably say "鍵を落とした". On the other hand, if you lost your key but you believe it's somewhere in your room, you will always prefer "なくした" over "落とした". "iPhone を落として割ってしまった" is an example where 落とす doesn't imply losing (you just dropped it).

Comment: @Yosh: do I get the meaning right? 落として割って　means I dropped it and then it broke?